# List out duplicated values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with duplicated values, how do I list those out

```
var result = [ { name: 'Maura Hickman' },
  { name: 'Elena Vega' },
  { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
  { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
  { name: 'Colon Reynolds' },
  { name: 'Luisa Rutledge' },
  { name: 'Pearson Marquez' },
  { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
  { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
  { name: 'Colon Reynolds' } ]
```

I have tried doing this

```
var obj = [ { name: 'Maura Hickman' },
  { name: 'Elena Vega' },
  { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
  { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
  { name: 'Colon Reynolds' },
  { name: 'Luisa Rutledge' },
  { name: 'Pearson Marquez' },
  { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
  { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
  { name: 'Colon Reynolds' } ];
if (Object.values(obj).indexOf('Jana Stevenson') > -1) {
   console.log('has Jana Stevenson');
}
```

but it didn't work.

what I am expecting is the following

```
var exist =  [{ name: 'Jana Stevenson'} , {name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
{ name: 'Colon Reynolds'}]
```

Comment: Is actual results expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all non-unique values (i.e.: duplicate/more than one occurrence) in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840781/get-all-non-unique-values-i-e-duplicate-more-than-one-occurrence-in-an-array)

Comment: please add a valid result. why is in the result only one `'Colon Reynolds'`, but for all other duplicates all of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and `findIndex()`

```js
var arr = [ { name: 'Maura Hickman' },
  { name: 'Elena Vega' },
  { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
  { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
  { name: 'Colon Reynolds' },
  { name: 'Luisa Rutledge' },
  { name: 'Pearson Marquez' },
  { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
  { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
  { name: 'Colon Reynolds' },
  { name: 'Colon Reynolds' }]
  
const res = arr.filter((x,i) => arr.findIndex(a => a.name === x.name) !== i)
               .filter((x,i,arr) => arr.find(a => a.name === x.name) === x);
              
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`Array#prototype#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), maintain a helper object, if the key is not already present in the accumulator add it, else push it into the accumulator and finally return the accumulator.

```js
result = [{
    name: 'Maura Hickman'
  },
  {
    name: 'Elena Vega'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sylvia Norman'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sylvia Norman'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sylvia Norman'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jana Stevenson'
  },
  {
    name: 'Colon Reynolds'
  },
  {
    name: 'Luisa Rutledge'
  },
  {
    name: 'Pearson Marquez'
  },
  {
    name: 'Sylvia Norman'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jana Stevenson'
  },
  {
    name: 'Colon Reynolds'
  }
];

// Take the groups which have more than 1 element in it
const duplicateNames = Object.values(result.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  // If not existing in accumulator add it
  if (!acc[curr.name]) {
  acc[curr.name] = [curr];
  }

  // Else push it simply
  else {
 acc[curr.name].push(curr);
  }

  return acc;
}, {}))
.filter(x => x.length > 1)
.map(x => x[0]);

console.log(duplicateNames);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for found names and take the object if found and if not found add the name to the set and return `false`.

```js
var array = [{ name: 'Maura Hickman' }, { name: 'Elena Vega' }, { name: 'Sylvia Norman' }, { name: 'Jana Stevenson' }, { name: 'Colon Reynolds' }, { name: 'Luisa Rutledge' }, { name: 'Pearson Marquez' }, { name: 'Sylvia Norman' }, { name: 'Jana Stevenson' }, { name: 'Colon Reynolds' }],
    found = new Set,
    duplicates = array.filter(({ name }) => found.has(name) || !found.add(name));

console.log(duplicates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you have an array, not an object. You shouldn't call your arrays object, as proven, this is confusing. Since `{} !== {}`, you'll need to actually check for the property you want to make sure to be unique. You can use below reducer, then recreate the array of objects structure.

```js
const res = arr.reduce((a, {name}) => ! a.includes(name) ? a.concat(name) : a, []).map(name => ({name}));
console.log(res)
```

```html
<script>
const arr = [ { name: 'Maura Hickman' },
    { name: 'Elena Vega' },
    { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
    { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
    { name: 'Colon Reynolds' },
    { name: 'Luisa Rutledge' },
    { name: 'Pearson Marquez' },
    { name: 'Sylvia Norman' },
    { name: 'Jana Stevenson' },
    { name: 'Colon Reynolds' } ];
</script>
```